# Python recognize classes as modules in import

Tags: python, django

I have a `Django` app with following structure:

```
my_app
--models
----__init__.py
----MyModelClass.py
--utils
----__init__.py
----MyBase.py
--admin.py
--urls.py
```

My models `__init__.py` file contains:

```
from .MyModelClass import MyModelClass  # noqa
```

My utils `__init__.py` file contains:

```
from .MyBase import MyBase  # noqa
```

Then when I tried to import `MyModelClass` in `MyBase` file with this:

```
from ..models import MyModelClass
```

or this:

```
from apps.my_app.models import MyModelClass
```

I got module instead of class. And then I should use:

```
MyModelClass.MyModelClass.objects.all()
```

**P.S** And even I got error when tried with this:

```
from ..models.MyModelClass import MyModelClass
```

**P.P.S** I have a `serializes` folder with similar folder structure in app where I store `Serializer` classes for Django Rest Framework. And in `MyModelClassSerializer.py`:

```
from ..models import MyModelClass

class MyModelClassSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModelClass
```

works as expected !

Comment: Don't call modules the same name as the classes. Python is not Java.

Comment: @DanielRoseman ok, will try to rename filename